# Password hash and verification don't match

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, cryptography, passwords

I'm writing custom forms authentication for ASP.NET MVC 5 (no, I don't want to use ASP.NET Identity). I'm trying to hash my passwords using a randomly-generated salt and then hashing `salt+password` using SHA512. Here are the methods I've written:

```
private static User SetPassword(User newUser, string password)
{
    var rand = RNGCryptoServiceProvider.Create();
    var saltBytes = new byte[128];
    var passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
    rand.GetNonZeroBytes(saltBytes);

    var passHash = SHA512Managed.Create().ComputeHash(saltBytes.Concat(passwordBytes).ToArray());

    var hash = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(passHash);
    var salt = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(saltBytes);

    newUser.PasswordHash = hash;
    newUser.Salt = salt;

    return newUser;
}

private static bool ValidatePassword(User user, string passwordTry)
{
    var actualPasswordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user.PasswordHash);

    var passwordTryBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwordTry);
    var saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user.Salt);

    var passwordTryHashBytes = SHA512Managed.Create().ComputeHash(saltBytes.Concat(passwordTryBytes).ToArray());
    if (passwordTryHashBytes == actualPasswordBytes)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If I step through the code, the registration (`SetPassword()`) method appears to work successfully. The user's record gets set with a UTF-8 encoded password hash and salt.

If I step through the password validation method, everything also appears to be operating normally. The user's record (the salt and hash) are checked against the password try.

The problem is, when I register with a password and then try to log in as that user, the password validation fails. I'm probably not understanding how one of the Cryptography classes works... can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

Comment: For anyone else using this code: I switched out the UTF8 encoding with a simple Byte to Hex conversion. It ended up being more stable and easier to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will always fail because both objects do not point to the same reference:

```
if (passwordTryHashBytes == actualPasswordBytes)
```

Try using LINQ's `SequenceEqual()` method

```
passwordTryHashBytes.SequenceEqual(actualPasswordBytes)
```

Comment: Ah, that was it! I forgot that arrays are reference types. Thanks!